# Merge two associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have two arrays in PHP that I want to merge.  An example of the first array, which is a list of Department and Classes, along with Class totals:

```
vdump($cl_subtotal);

array(2) {
 'None' → array(1) {
 'None' → float 132.88
}

'instore bakery' → array(10) {
  'pies' → float 70.94
  'cakes' → float 146.71
  'miscellaneous' → float 25.57
  'cookies' → float 52.38
  'brownies' → float 33.96
  'rolls' → float 143.02
  'danish' → float 90.42
  'bagels & pretzels' → float 85.68
  'breads' → float 55.73
  'dessert case' → float 81.83
 }
}
```

The second array is the Class detail records, and I want them to appear under each Class in the first array.  There's a catch.  In this second array, if there is no Department or Class, the array key is blank ('').  The Department/Class will always both be blank, or they will both contain a string (so there will never be a case where Department is blank, but Class is not blank).  These records with blank Department/Class in the second array should be associated with the record in the first array where Department = "None" and Class = "None".

This is an example of the second array:

```
 vdump($groups);

 array(2) {
 'instore bakery' → array(10) {
   'pies' → array(2) {
     [0] => array(12) {
    'UPC' → str•13 '0004712503209'
    'Department_Desc' → str•14 'instore bakery'
    'Class_Desc' → str•4 'pies'
    'store' → str•2 '11'
    'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
    'invoice_number' → str•11 'DI613728199'
    'seq' → str•1 '1'
    'item_id' → str•14 '00047125032097'
    'item_description' → str•9 'MARIONBRY'
    'dept_number' → str•2 '17'
    'final_qty' → str•4 '5.00'
    'final_cost' → str•5 '37.65'
  }
```

and here's an example record with blank Department/Class:

```
     [""] => array(1) {
       [""] => array(4) {
        [0] => array(10) {
        'store' → str•2 '11'
        'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
        'invoice_number' → str•11 'DI613728199'
        'seq' → str•1 '8'
        'item_id' → str•14 '00047125032332'
        'UPC' → str•13 '0004712503233'
        'item_description' → str•9 'NOT FOUND'
        'dept_number' → str•1 '0'
       'final_qty' → str•4 '2.00'
        'final_cost' → str•5 '20.96'
     }
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php ... you could at least try, even if this is not your 100% out of the box solution. might be you also need foreach ... php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You can use array_merge() function for this.

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2/*, $arrayN, $arrayN*/);

Comment: I understand I likely need array_merge.  My trouble is how to iterate through the arrays and make the comparison so that the merge happens correctly.  In particular, I'm stuck at how to use foreach when the array keys are strings.              foreach($groups as $k => $r) {
                if ($k == '') {echo 'blank';}
                foreach($r as $item => $v) {
                    foreach($cl_subtotal as &$inv1) {
                        if($inv1 == )  //How do I refer to $inv1 here?  I feel like I need a key, but it's a string that isn't always the same value
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I resolved this:
I first replaced the empty keys in the second array ($groups).  I then did:

```
            foreach($cl_subtotal as $grname => &$itemlist ){
            foreach($itemlist as $ilk => &$ilv){
                $ilv = array(
                    'value' => $ilv,
                );
                foreach($groups[$grname][$ilk] as $k => $v) {
                    $ilv[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
```

to merge the array with details into the summary array.